# li:hover won't change sprite position

Tags: html, css

I have an li that is attached to an id for javascript and a class to css. The css is not changing the image on li:hover. am I missing something? Any help is much appreciated! Sorry if this isn't displaying properly, I don't get to post much.

```
  HTML
  <div id="navlist">
    <ul>
    <li id="asteriskChecking" class="asteriskChecking"></li>
    <li id="plusChecking" class="plusChecking"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

CSS
.asteriskChecking {background:url('http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/Buttons.png') 0px 0px;}
.asteriskChecking li:hover{background: url('http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/Buttons.png') 0px -50px;}

.plusChecking {background:url('http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/Buttons.png') 203px 0px;}
.plusChecking li:hover{background: url('http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/Buttons.png') 203px -50px;}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this is not supported in ie6. Reference: http://www.virtuosimedia.com/dev/css/ultimate-ie6-cheatsheet-how-to-fix-25-internet-explorer-6-bugs#no-hover-state

Comment: @Scott, true.. not supported by IE6 but in turn IE6 is not supported by Microsoft ;) so it is time to let IE6 (*at least*) rest in peace..

Answer (score 2):

You are applying the image on the `.asteriskChecking` but the different position on the the `asteriskChecking li` element.. (*which does not exist*)

Use `.plusChecking:hover` and `.asteriskChecking:hover`

You also do not need to reapply the image .. just the position change..

```
.asteriskChecking {
    background:url('http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/Buttons.png') 0px 0px;
}
.asteriskChecking:hover{
    background-position: 0px -50px;
}

.plusChecking {
    background:url('http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/Buttons.png') 203px 0px;
}
.plusChecking:hover{
    background-position: 203px -50px;
}
```

Comment: Wow...this has worked. I always assumed that :hover had to be attached to a tag. I didn't know you could attach it to the class/id. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The selector `.asteriskChecking li:hover` means "a `li` tag that is hovered, inside an element with a class of `asteriskChecking`".

You have an `li` element *with* a class of `asteriskChecking`, not inside it. So, your selector should read:

```
li.asteriskChecking:hover { /* your definitions */ }
```